# Talend - compare 2 files and keep entries that are not common to both

Tags: diff, talend

I follow this [solution to compare two files in Talend Open Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227687/compare-2-files-and-keep-entries-that-are-not-common-to-both).

It's seem to work but in my output file, I only have commas for each line. But the number of lines is correct.

I don't understand why.

Comment: only coma for each lines means no data only coma`s `, , ,` are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're not properly defining an output schema and the associated data for the defined columns.

Your tMap should look something like this:

[image: tMap configuration]

Where I've joined 2 files that have an id, a name and an age.

What is worth mentioning is that Gabriele's answer in that question will only test the diff one way. To get a bidirectional diff of the files you'll want to replicate the job and switch the main flow and the lookup of the files and output both of these to a tBufferOutput component and then read them back in with a tBufferInput component and output this as your diff file.

So your job might end up looking like this:

[image: job set up]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You right, I link out2 with row45 instead of row44 (on your schema)